# how to call a conversion using double component UIPickerview

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

I will post my code below as a quick note I define both of the components in my .h file and I need to call an action when certain rows are picked. For example something like if row in component == 0 and other component == 1 do this?
Still new to iPhone Programing thank you in advanced!!!

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
return 2;

}


  -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:    
 (NSInteger)component{
if (component==kapickerComponent) {
    return [parentarray count];

}
if (component == kbpickerComponent) {
    return [subarray count];
}

}


 -(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow: 
(NSInteger)rowforComponent:(NSInteger)component{
if (component == kapickerComponent) {
    return [self.parentarray objectAtIndex:row];
}
if (component == kbpickerComponent) {
    return [self.subarray objectAtIndex:row];
}

}

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row 
inComponent:(NSInteger)component {



 if ( row. kapickerComponent ==0, and row.kbpickerComponent==1 ??????????? ){
    float number1 = ([initamount.text floatValue ]);
    initamount.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@" ", number1];
    double answer = number1 *12;
    result.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@" ", answer];

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row 
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if ([thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:kapickerComponent] == 0 && [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:kbpickerComponent] == 1) {
        float number1 = [initamount.text floatValue];
        initamount.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f", number1];
        double answer = number1 *12;
        result.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", answer];
    }
}
```

Comment: okay thank you. i just tried that and it turned an error or " member reference base ype 'int' not a structure or union" any thoughts?

Comment: kapickerComponent is an integer for the component right? So you need row 0 from kapickerComponent and row 1 from kbpickerComponent?

Comment: yea I'm doing a unit converter and have kapickerComponent filled with an array of units and same with kbpickerComponenet and so when a certain row of both get called i need to write a statement to do the calculation.

Comment: pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent: is only called once each time a user selects a row. So you will need to either save the selected choice, or use [thePickerView selectedRowInComponent: kapickerComponent] == 0. I'll edit my post to use that

Answer (score 0):

if ( kapickerComponent.row == 0 && kbpickerComponent.row
==1){// Ur CODE HERE}

Comment: thank you but it has an error of "member reference base ype 'int' not a structure or union" i can't seem to figure it out